# Why is persist used like an action in Holden Karau's book "Learning Spark"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading "Learning spark", and noticed this kind of code:

```
val result = input.map(x => x * x)
result.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
println(result.count())
println(result.collect().mkString(","))
```

does this code really persist the `result rdd`? I thought in Spark everything was immutable, but in this case it looks like we are mutating the `result rdd`.

Shouldn't this piece of code be written like this? :

```
val result = input.map(x => x * x)
val persistedResult = result.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
println(persistedResult.count())
println(persistedResult.collect().mkString(","))
```

There are many more code samples like this in the book, so that got me wondering...

Comment: Both ways are equivalent in this case (for `cache`/`persist`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike typed transformations, [`persist()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@persist(newLevel:org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel):Dataset.this.type) is applied to *this* dataset. This is because `persist` actually only **marks** dataset as such. From [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence):

> You can mark an RDD to be persisted using the persist() or cache()
>   methods on it. The first time it is computed in an action, it will be
>   kept in memory on the nodes.